# Merge Skype and Gmail contacts

Tags: 2.1-eclair, contacts, skype

I recently installed Skype on my phone, and so all of my Skype contacts are added to the full list of contacts in my phone. However, most of these contacts are redundant. A few of the redundancies were automatically detected by Skype, and so the two versions of the contact are merged together.

But many weren't, and I need to way to manually do that. Right now, I have many contacts that show up double on my contacts list (once for gmail+phone info, and once for skype info). I've been poking around but I can't find a way to manually merge these two contacts. Skype contacts don't show up at my desktop Gmail contacts list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not positive when it was added, but if you open one of the duplicate contacts and edit it, you can press Menu>Join to collapse two entries into one.